# Add fading effect in songs playlist using AVAudioPlayer and MPMusicPlayerController in ios

Tags: iphone, ios

I need to add fade in/out feature in songs playlist (playlist songs are retrive from ipod library).
When one song end i need to fade out effect and next song start i need to fade in effect
and one other think during fading system or media VOLUME should not changed.

I am using MPMusicPlayerController for play song.

Answer (score 1):

Here is an extension to AVAudioPlayer that I wrote (pre-ARC) that does exactly what you want.

The header `AVAudioPlayer+FadeControl.h`:

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
#import <AVFoundation/AVFoundation.h>


@interface AVAudioPlayer (FadeControl)

-(void)fadeOutWithDuration:(NSTimeInterval)inFadeOutTime;

@end
```

And the source `AVAudioPlayer+FadeControl.m`:

```
#import "AVAudioPlayer+FadeControl.h"

#define     kFadeSteps  20.0

@implementation AVAudioPlayer (FadeControl)

-(void)fadeOutWithDuration:(NSTimeInterval)inFadeOutTime
{
    NSTimeInterval fireInterval = inFadeOutTime/kFadeSteps;
    float volumeDecrement = 1.0/kFadeSteps;
    float originalVolume = self.volume;

    self.volume = originalVolume - volumeDecrement;

    [self retain];
    [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:fireInterval target:self selector:@selector(fadeOutTimerMethod:) userInfo:[NSNumber numberWithFloat:originalVolume] repeats:YES];

}

- (void)fadeOutTimerMethod:(NSTimer*)theTimer   
{
    float volumeDecrement = 1.0/kFadeSteps;

    if (self.volume > volumeDecrement)
    {
        self.volume = self.volume - volumeDecrement;
    }
    else if ( [theTimer isValid] )
    {
        [self stop];

        NSNumber* originalVolume = [theTimer userInfo];
        self.volume = [originalVolume floatValue];

        [theTimer invalidate];
    }
    else 
    {
        [self stop];
        [self release];
    }


}

@end
```

It should be trivial to ad an `playWithFadeInDuration:` method. To use in an ARC project, just add `-fno-objc-arc` to the file's compile flags.

Comment: This method is working but it decrease system volume so it is not helpful for me 
Please give idea how can i decrease volume(fade out) without change system volume.
What is self.volume??????????

Comment: The same general approach would work for `MPMusicPlayerController`.

Comment: It's working but it decrease system or media player music which is not a right way....I want to do fading without system volume increase/decrease.

thanks again for give reply

Answer (score 0):

```
-(void)doFadeInVolume { 

//play
[audioPlayerMain play];

if (audioPlayerMain.volume < 1.0) {
audioPlayerMain.volume = audioPlayerMain.volume + 0.1;
[self performSelector:@selector(doVolumeFadeMainIn) withObject:nil afterDelay:0.2];
} 
}
```

And can use the opposite approach for fading out the volume.  Hope this helps.

Comment: @PratikPatel Yes, this is assuming you are using `AVAudioPlayer`.  In the header file aka interface file you would declare it as `AVAudioPlayer *audioPlayerMain` as is done in my example above.

Comment: same as @Pratik Patel How can i done it using MPMusicPlayerController?????